# How to stop flex display overriding on grid display?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

My aim is to create a layout initially having grid display and for each direct child inside that, having flex display for perfect centering the items inside them, so far, it worked out until I gave one `.wrapper`(the first parent)'s child(`.nested`) some children and I gave the `.nested` `display: grid;`; but for some reason the `display: grid` of the `.nested` is omitted and doesn't take the `grid-auto-rows: 100px` property, which is my problem.

I digged out everywhere for a solution but couldn't find one, Can anybody help me with this issue?

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
main{
    max-width: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
    padding: 0 50px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
.wrapper > div{
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
}
.nested{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: 100px !important;
}
.wrapper .nested div{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="box box2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="box box3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="box box4">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, asperiores at atque beatae cum cupiditate doloremque, error est, eveniet laboriosam nihil officiis pariatur porro rem tempore. A accusamus animi delectus, dolore eaque eveniet impedit maiores molestiae perspiciatis quidem sequi, veniam?
        </div>
        <div class="box box5">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="box box6 nested">
            <div>lorem</div>
            <div>lorem</div>
            <div>lorem</div>
            <div>lorem</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box box7">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="box box8">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="box box9">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="box box10">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="box box11">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not sure why are you repeating the same question when I already (1) gave you the answer and (2) the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the selector in your css file is wrong and you have to replace it

you have to replace this selector

```
.nested{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: 100px !important;
}
```

with this

```
.wrapper > div.nested{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: 100px !important;
}
```

for better debugging check regularly in your DevTool

Comment: Nice that it was, but I still can't understand what's wrong with selecting .nested?

Comment: Read this articles https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Comment: or this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

Well you are overriding the display:grid with display:flex because ".wrapper > div" has higher precedence than ".nested".

You could potentially add a new div inside box6 for the nested class...

```
   <div class="box box6">
        <div class="nested">
            <div>lorem</div>
            <div>lorem</div>
            <div>lorem</div>
            <div>lorem</div>
         </div>
    </div>
```